# Failed resolution of: java/nio/file/Paths;

Tags: java, android, nio

In my code I do this:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(mMyDir));
```

But I have this error on some android devices:

> Failed resolution of: java/nio/file/Paths;

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your `minSdkVersion` to 26 or higher, as [that class is relatively new](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Paths).

Alternatively, do not use `Paths`. Since [you have limited access to files on Android Q and higher](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html), you may need to be considering other approaches anyway.

Comment: Thanks! but with other appoach?

Comment: @loki: Either you need to stick to locations that you have access to (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`) or use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`).